# How to declare variables in Visual Studios immediate window in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, immediate-window

Recently I discovered that it's possible to [declare variables in the Visual Studio immediate window](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121623/10-Tips-you-should-know-about-Watch-Window-While-d) while debugging.  This feature is really useful because if I want to experiment with the code in that context, I can create new variables without modifying the real code in the new window, and I can then explore them in the watch window.

This works great for a C# project I have been debugging, but now I'm trying to do the same thing for a basic C++ declaration in a different project.  I break at my breakpoint, and type the following into the immediate window:

```
int myVariable;
```

This gives the error:

```
CXX0013: Error: missing operator
```

Are there any steps that I need to get this to work with a C++ project?

Comment: Managed code is a tool builder's delight.  This is not available in the C++ IDE.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The immediate window for C++ is extremely limited; I don't think you can declare a variable like that (or even what behavior you would expect).

Comment: [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/c46d84af-5a77-4313-99d6-7cfbd16943a1) seems to say it's C# only - not even possible in VB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can accomplish the same functionality by adding the new variable to your code window (rather than immediate window) while stopped in the debugger.

Make sure you have *Tools->Options->Debugging->Edit and Continue->Enable native Edit and Continue* checked.

```
int myVariable=444;
```

Then add your code, *Debug->Apply Code Changes*, and it works. Optionally use *Set Next Statement* to move the execution point to a different line.

Comment: When you say code window, do you mean the source code that I'm stopped the debugger in? Yeah, that I know, but by checking off _Enable native Edit and Continue_, is that it disables the _data viewing enhancements_ i.e. [data natural visualization](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Writing-type-visualizers-2eae77a2) which is not acceptable. :(  Also, in some cases, e.g. debugging a .dll, this will not work esp if the .dll is in use elsewhere (I've run in to this problem)