# How to create a temporary variables on the fly in the Immediate Window in MSVS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I've seen on [this page](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/10/26/10-tips-you-should-know-about-watch-window-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/) that temporary variables can be declared in MSVS.

> Here is another Tricks (sic), you can use some “temp” variable to store those data. But you have to declare the variable at “Immediate Window”. [ Please read Tips 3 to know more about using Immediate window with Watch Window ]

However, this doesn't appear to actually work.  If I were to do this for instance:

```
int test;
```

I get a `type name is not allowed`.  If I do this:

```
CString s;
```

I get an `identifier "s" is undefined`.

Looking at `Tip 3` doesn't appear to help.

Considering that this article is dated 2010, I'm assuming that this is for MSVS 2010, but I'd like to get this to work for MSVS 2013.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using C++.  But it would be good if I could do this for any language that the MSVS debugger can handle.

Comment: Ah well, there you go. The C++ debugger is not nearly as powerful as the .NET one (mostly because there's a lot less leeway in terms of dynamic code compilation).

Comment: Is there a link from MS stating that this is not possible to do?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [VS Immediate Window for C++ Declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648455/vs-immediate-window-for-c-declarations). I don't know of any official documentation stating as much, but I'm fairly certain it's not supported. The debug engines are different behind the scenes.

Comment: By checking off _Enable native Edit and Continue_, it disables the _data viewing enhancements_  i.e. [data natural visualization](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Writing-type-visualizers-2eae77a2) which is not acceptable. :(  Also, in some cases, e.g. debugging a .dll, this will not work esp if the .dll is in use elsewhere (I've run in to this problem).